# Adobe DTM and arrays with varying numbers of elements

Tags: javascript, dynamic, tags, adobe, adobe-analytics

On our site, we have pages that can be assigned tags, and I'm having issues with figuring out how to handle this with Adobe DTM/Analytics. Each page can have between 1 and `n` tags being captured in an array. I can see them in the developer console just fine, ex:

```
> data.page.termIds 
< [513, 1787, 115, 4330]
```

Each element corresponds to the tag ID.

I've been searching online but can't find any answers that really help me. [This](http://webanalyticsfordevelopers.com/2015/06/02/quick-tip-dtm-data-elements-arrays/) blog post is close, but it looks like they need to create a separate data element for each element in the array. I also found [this](http://www.minzdravkub.ru/content/adobeforums/en/marketing-cloud-forum/activation.topic.html/forum__a4ff-i_tried_to_saveaja.html) question in the adobe forums, but it's similar to the blog post.

Does anyone know if this is even possible? Are we expected to create a block of data elements, with each one assigned to an array index?

Answer (score 1):

Do not bother with the **JS Object** option unless you want to target a top level js object/variable. So for example `foobar` is okay but `foo['bar']` or `foo.bar` is not.  If you want to target anything "nested", skip **JS Object** and use **Custom Script** to check for it and return it, instead. This is because DTM doesn't do a good job of parsing or checking if the parent nodes exist before returning it. This is basically what was already said in the blog link you mentioned.

As for what the **Data Element** is returning and how to use it...the **Data Element** itself will have a return value of exactly what you return. So if you return an object, it will be an object. If you return an array, it will be an array.  The trick (or caveat, or bug, depending on how you want to look at it) is how you reference or use the **Data Element** within the tools and rules.

The long story short of it is this: If you intend to use the `%data_element_name%` syntax (e.g. in any of the built in form fields in the rules, config settings, etc.) then you should only have your **Data Element** return a `string` type value (this is basically the issue the forum post link had, and I assume the issue you are running into).

If you want to be able to access it as some other type (e.g. the array, or js object in general), you need to use `_satellite.getVar('data_element_name')` syntax.  The obvious drawback to this is it basically makes using DTM in a "non-coder" way useless in that you cannot use this in any of the built-in fields in rules. You can only use it in contexts where you can write javascript, e.g. **Data > Custom** type **Conditions** or in **Javascript / 3rd Party Tag** containers.

But one question for you is, what are you ultimately using the **Data Element** for? For example, if the end game here is you are looking to populate a `prop` or `eVar` or some other variable with a comma delimited string.. well just return your array as such in your **Data Element** and then you can use the `%data_element_name%` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing the data is one thing and formatting is another.

My question is how do you need to see this data organized in reporting? Capturing the array itself doesn't do much unless you know what format you need it in. Are you hoping to capture these IDs and classify them? Do you want to see the array list by page?

Can you provide more detail on how you'll be reporting on these values?